# Null array from a JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i'm having some troubles parsing a JSON rendered array that come from a ruby function, into a JAVASCRIPT array.

Ruby function that genereta 12 random numbers from "s" to "e":

```
def genArrayNum(s,e)
start=s
i=0
nums=Array.new
array=Array.new
         while s<e
          nums.push s+1
          s+=1
         end
  while i<12
    j=rand(0..11)
    array.push nums[j]
    nums.delete_at(j)
    i+=1
  end
 return array
end
```

Ruby function that render a JSON array that i will pass to a AJAX function that i will call from a button:

```
def generateSound
i=0
 path="audios/"
 s=Puntata2.find(2).audioStart
 e=Puntata2.find(2).audioEnd
 array=genArrayNum(s,e)
 array2=Array.new
  while i<12
   param=path+StimoloAudio.find(array[i]).name
   array2.push param
   i+=1
  end
 render json:{arr2:array2}
end
```

The 2 Ruby functions correctly work generating all the paths of the sounds that i need

Here the JS functions:

```
function call_ajaxEs2(){
  $.ajax({ type:'POST', url:'/esercizio2s/generateSound',data{},
    success:function(data){
      var obj=JSON.parse(data.arr2);
      return obj;
    },
    error:function(){
    alert("Error call_ajaxEs2()");
   }
});
```

}
Now i call this function where i've parsed the array:

```
function stickman(){
  var arr=call_ajaxEs2();
  var stickCounter=0;
    if(stickCounter<12){
      if(arr=null)alert("arr null");
      document.getElementById('cloud-sndEs2').setAttribute("src",arr[stickCounter]);
     stickCounter++;
   }else alert("end stickman");
 }
```

So the problem is: everytime that i refresh the page or i start the page the `alert("arr null")` appear, so that means that the array that i've parsed is empty.
So where am i wrong? Where is the error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous, so return won't be enough. Make the function call from your ajax.

```js
function call_ajaxEs2() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/esercizio2s/generateSound',
    data {},
    success: function(data) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(data.arr2);
      stickmancb(obj);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error call_ajaxEs2()");
    }
  });
}

function stickman() {
  call_ajaxEs2();
}

function stickmancb(arr) {
  var stickCounter = 0;
  if (stickCounter < 12) {
    if (arr = null) alert("arr null");
    document.getElementById('cloud-sndEs2').setAttribute("src", arr[stickCounter]);
    stickCounter++;
  } else alert("end stickman");
}
```

Comment: i've forgot to tell you that i call the function stickman() from a button called "stickman", because i need to change and reproduce the target sound everytime i click on it, i mean: first click i hear the sound, second click the sound change with the next one and reproduce it, and i do this operation until i reach 12 sounds reproduced

Comment: @luke sorry for the late reply. I updated the answer.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data... so now i think that the problem is the JSON that i generate from the ruby function...

Comment: @LukeSmith try after removing the `JSON.parse()`. Like `var obj = data.arr2;`